# Calculations through user input

Tags: java, math, user-input

Can someone point me into the right direction on how to make a function that allows the user to make calculations.

I'd like it to work as shown below:

```
java Calculate 8*8  
the answer = 64

java Calculate 7+(8*2)
the answer = 23
```

The basic math operators are what I'd like to get working first, using parentheses is the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    //pass in the string containing the operation, for example:
    double multiplication = (double) engine.eval(args[0]); 
}
```

Comment: See also this neat [example of the `ScriptEngine` with a GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).

Answer (score 1):

**Working code:**

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test   {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your calculation: ");
        String userInput = in.next();
        //pass in the string containing the operation, for example:
        double calculation = (Double) engine.eval(userInput); 
        System.out.print("The answer = " + calculation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

[Is there an eval() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java)

You can pass arguments from the command line using the main method.

```
public class Calculate{
    public static void main(String... args){
        if(args.length == 0){
            System.err.println("You forgot to add a formulate to run");
            return;
        }
        String formula = args[0];
        // Insert the formula into code from the link mentioned above
    }
}
```